# Android long click listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, onitemlongclicklistener

I'm creating a simple Android app so I can play around with a few cool things and test out how Android really works. So far I've been able to successfully incorporate the Navigation Drawer, multiple fragments in one activity, and a datasource connection. My issue is that when I'm trying to create a long click listener so I can delete items out of a list, the app "Unexpectedly Closes". I have 3 fragments named WeekFragment, MonthFragment, and CustomFragment.

```
public static WeekFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    WeekFragment fragment = new WeekFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public WeekFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_week, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((MainActivity)activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    dataSource = new DataSource(getActivity());
    dataSource.open();

    trans = dataSource.getAllTransactions("Date");

    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, trans);

    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.transactionListWeek);
    listView.setLongClickable(true);
    listView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long row_id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "PLS WORK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

The other 2 fragments deliver the same issue, I have not been able to see any errors in the log. (I'm using Android Studio).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Logcat Stack Trace

```
07-11 22:54:48.125  25117-25117/financialtracker.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: financialtracker.app, PID: 25117
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3005)
        at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$ActionModeImpl.dispatchOnCreate(ActionBarImpl.java:1021)
        at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.startActionMode(ActionBarImpl.java:550)
        at android.app.Activity.onWindowStartingActionMode(Activity.java:5191)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:341)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2617)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2604)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
        at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:4731)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:3565)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:3521)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace from your logcat.

Comment: Also, what is your minSdkVersion set to?

Comment: The minSdkVersion is set to 19

Comment: You need to call `setMultiChoiceModeListener()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get your ListView to handle long clicks as you have it setup, you'll need to change the following line:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
```

to:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Or, depending on how you plan to select and remove items, you might remove it completely.

Comment: What are the differences between the two?

Comment: `MODAL` is to be used with a Contextual Action Bar, which you're not setup for, which is why it's crashing.

Comment: No sweat. Someone disagrees with me, though, and I'm not sure why. I'll let you know if I find out that I've told you something wrong.

Comment: I didn't see any difference between the two options you give. I'm new to multi-choice mode as well. I didn't know that you only need to set the MultiChoiceModeListener for the modal version.

Comment: worked for me where I had three fragments in main activity and long press on list item was crashing the app. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`, you need to implement `MultiChoiceModeListener` and call `setMultiChoiceModeListener()`. See my [CheckableLinearLayout](https://github.com/codeguru42/CheckableLinearLayout) for an example.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to take a look at it and learn something different!